# Many views or one?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios, uikit

I have a task to write RSS reader for iOS. 
For it I created navigation-based application.
I want to display list of RSS channels in the UITableView. When user clicks on one of this channels application must display list of items of chosen channel. What is better: use separated views with UITableView for RSS channels and for items, or display channels and items in single view and single UITable(if user wants to see channels, he see channels, if he wants to see items, he see items)? And maybe is there good code example of navigator-based application?

Comment: Post a screenshot of both use cases. Normally with UITableViews you want to display one level of detail per view. When a user taps on an item, you show the next level of detail. You shouldn't have two sets of information in a cell unless you have something like a story summary in the detailTextLabel.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you're asking... However I can help you with your last question about the navigation based application.  Here's a tutorial (I didn't create it) on how to use an RSS reader with a navigation controller: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial.

Hope this helps.